# Why is color different between simulator and my iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My project's written by swift. Everything's right when i build it on simulator, but everything about color is wrong when i build it on my iPhone. Color and image's color have fader color than the original! Please help me!

Comment: Have you changed any accessibility settings on your phone?  Can you post screen shots of both?

Comment: Perhaps your monitor is a better screen than Your iPhone?

Comment: @Jhecht i use retina macbook pro and iPhone 4s :(

Comment: @jeffamaphone if i capture iphone screenshot and open it on my mac, it will be right color! what's happen with my iphone ?? :(

Comment: Perhaps your device is damaged.  Take it to the Genius bar.

Comment: Is this a problem only for your app? Or do other apps also look off (when compared to screenshots)?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS Go to **System Preferences**  >> **Displays** >> Select **Color** tab  than change **Display profile**  to **Generic RGB profile**.

[image]

If this still not works than click on **Calibrate** button from same and set up desire accuracy you want.

Comment: it does not work for me, i take a photo for clear [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37bytehz95ncqw6/IMG_0480.JPG?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone is not color managed. It does not include ColorSync or any other color matching technology. This is currently a limitation of the OS and/or hardware, unfortunately.

Comment: this is my problem :( [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37bytehz95ncqw6/IMG_0480.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Have you considered writing an app for the phone where you can enter color values yourself and attempting to match it that way? Once you've found the color on the phone, you can use whatever values you've come up with in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the precise physical capabilities of the display of an iPhone and the Mac greatly differ.

What you can do is add some extra values to simulator's RGB.

- Red +12
- Green +19
- Blue +16

This will give color near to what you want in iPhone.

Comment: The colors aren't just a little bit off; they're literally black and white difference (simulator shows white background; real device shows black background)